# How to add jquery to my custom post type wp plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, jquery, metabox

I want to include a jquery to my wordpress custom post type plugin which i have created.

i have two doubt,,,

1. the jquery script will work only on widget options (i.e) Sidebar. So when i use the widget option the jquery script have to work. i am using the script to slide my custom post contents. so it will have to work only on sidebars?
2. How do i display meta box contents in widgets?

Can any one suggest me.

Thanks .

Comment: This is _two_ questions and both are not quite clear. Please try to ask one question at a time and elaborate more at what you have implemented and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rarst I have created a cpt testimonial plugin. In that i want to add jquery to perform rotate option ?. The rotating option should go for only on widgets.